# ReactJS Kanban Board Drag and Drop without using external libraries

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a Kanban Board in ReactJS. All the stages are stored as a JSON with their respective tasks. I want to be able to drag and drop a task to a given stage headline in order to move it from one stage to another.

This is my Kanban Board:

[image]

When I drag and drop a task over a headline I am unable to get the correct stage. I have tried to log it but the data given for the const `handleOnDragOver` to the log is just "undefined":

> DragAndDropDemo() :: handleOnDragOver() :: e.target.name=undefined
> e.target.value=undefined

ReactJS Code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export function DragAndDropDemo() {

  /* Stages with tasks */
  const [stages, setStages] = useState([                      
    {
        name: "todo", 
        bgcolor: "green",
        tasks: [
            {name: "Integrate Slack"}
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "wip", 
        bgcolor: "yellow",
        tasks: [
            {name: "Learn Angular"},
            {name: "React"}
        ]
    },                        
    {
        name: "complete", 
        bgcolor: "orange",
        tasks: [
            {name: "Vue"}
        ]
    }                
  ]);

  /* Handle Drag and Drop */
  const handleOnDragStart = e => {
    console.log("DragAndDropDemo() :: handleOnDragStart() :: e.target.name="  + e.target.name + " e.target.value="  + e.target.value)
    
  };
  const handleOnDragOver = e => {
    console.log("DragAndDropDemo() :: handleOnDragOver() :: e.target.name="  + e.target.name + " e.target.value="  + e.target.value)
  };
  const handleOnDrop = e => {
    console.log("DragAndDropDemo() :: handleOnDrop() :: e.target.name="  + e.target.name + " e.target.value="  + e.target.value)
  };

  

  return (
    <div>
    {stages.map((stage_item, stage_index) => {
        const tasks = stage_item["tasks"];
        return (
          <div key={stage_index} style={{backgroundColor: stage_item.bgcolor, float: "left", border: "#000 1px solid"}}>
            <h2 id={stage_item.name} className="droppable" onDragOver={handleOnDragOver} onDrop={handleOnDrop} style={{border: "#000 1px dashed", padding: "10px", margin: "1px"}}>{stage_item.name}</h2>

            
            {tasks.map((task_item, task_index) => {
                return(
                <div key={task_index} onDragStart={handleOnDragStart} draggable className="draggable"  style={{backgroundColor: "white", border: "#ccc 1px solid", padding: "10px"}}>
                    <p>{task_item.name}</p>
                </div>
                );
            })}
          </div>
        )
      })}
      <div style={{clear: "both"}}></div>

    </div>
    );
}
  
export default DragAndDropDemo;
```

Comment: In order, if you will need to drag & drop with some swap effects: https://codesandbox.io/s/drag-swap-qv6s0x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the dataTransfer property on the start event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API#define_the_drags_data

So to for example pass the dragged elements id to the drop event you can do use the setData function of the dataTransfer object in the start event handler and then use the getData in the drop event handler. Like this:

```
 import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";

export function DragAndDropDemo() {
  /* Stages with tasks */
  const [stages, setStages] = useState([
    {
      name: "todo",
      bgcolor: "green",
      tasks: [{ name: "Integrate Slack" }]
    },
    {
      name: "wip",
      bgcolor: "yellow",
      tasks: [{ name: "Learn Angular" }, { name: "React" }]
    },
    {
      name: "complete",
      bgcolor: "orange",
      tasks: [{ name: "Vue" }]
    }
  ]);

  /* Handle Drag and Drop */
  const handleOnDragStart = (e) => {
    console.log("start", e);
    e.dataTransfer.setData("application/my-app", e.target.id);

    console.log(
      "DragAndDropDemo() :: handleOnDragStart() :: e.target.name=" +
        e.target.name +
        " e.target.value=" +
        e.target.value
    );
  };

  const handleOnDragOver = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";

    console.log(
      "DragAndDropDemo() :: handleOnDragOver() :: e.target.name=" +
        e.target.name +
        " e.target.value=" +
        e.target.value
    );
  };

  const handleOnDrop = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const data = e.dataTransfer.getData("application/my-app");
    console.log("data", data);

    console.log(
      "DragAndDropDemo() :: handleOnDrop() :: e.target.name=" +
        e.target.name +
        " e.target.value=" +
        e.target.value
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {stages.map((stage_item, stage_index) => {
        const tasks = stage_item["tasks"];
        return (
          <div
            key={stage_index}
            style={{
              backgroundColor: stage_item.bgcolor,
              float: "left",
              border: "#000 1px solid"
            }}
          >
            <h2
              id={stage_item.name}
              className="droppable"
              onDragOver={(e) => handleOnDragOver(e)}
              onDrop={handleOnDrop}
              style={{
                border: "#000 1px dashed",
                padding: "10px",
                margin: "1px"
              }}
            >
              {stage_item.name}
            </h2>

            {tasks.map((task_item, task_index) => {
              return (
                <div
                  key={task_index}
                  onDragStart={handleOnDragStart}
                  draggable
                  id={task_item.name}
                  className="draggable"
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: "white",
                    border: "#ccc 1px solid",
                    padding: "10px"
                  }}
                >
                  <p>{task_item.name}</p>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        );
      })}
      <div style={{ clear: "both" }}></div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default DragAndDropDemo;
```